# Getting even figure widths in grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to plot three figures using `grid.arrange` of `R`'s`gridExtra` package. I want them to appear as 3 columns in one row, where the left most figure should have the y-axis but no legend, the middle figure no y-axis and no legend, and the right most figure should have no y-axis but should include the legend. That way the legend and y-axis, which are identical to all figures, appear only once.

Here are the data - they relate to gene ontology enrichment tests:

First, the color scheme of the legend - a color for each enrichment p-value range:

```
color.order <- c("#7d4343","#B20000","#C74747","#E09898","#EBCCD6","#C8C8C8")
names(color.order) <- c("(0-0.05]","(0.05-0.1]","(0.1-0.15]","(0.15-0.2]","(0.2-0.25]","(0.25-1]")
```

Then the figure `data.frame`s:

```
df.g1 <- data.frame(category=c("C1-up","C1-down","C2-up","C2-down"),
                 p.value=c(0.4833,0.5114,0.3487,0.6522),log10.p.value=c(3.157832,2.912393,4.575481,1.856192),
                 col=c("(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]"),
                 col.cat=c("(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]"))
df.g2 <- data.frame(category=c("C1-up","C1-down","C2-up","C2-down"),
                    p.value=c(0.5345,0.4819,0.9986,0.0013),log10.p.value=c(2.720522905,3.170430737,0.006084383,28.860566477),
                    col=c("(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0-0.05]"),
                    col.cat=c("(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0-0.05]"))
df.g3 <- data.frame(category=c("C1-up","C1-down","C2-up","C2-down"),
                    p.value=c(0.2262,0.7703,0.9926,0.0080),log10.p.value=c(6.45507399,1.13340102,0.03225729,20.96910013),
                    col=c("(0.2-0.25]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0-0.05]"),
                    col.cat=c("(0.2-0.25]","(0.25-1]","(0.25-1]","(0-0.05]"))
```

Putting them together in a list:

```
df.list <- list(g1=df.g1,g2=df.g2,g3=df.g3)
```

This is for the legend which associates p-value ranges with colors:

```
color.order <- c("#7d4343","#B20000","#C74747","#E09898","#EBCCD6","#C8C8C8")
names(color.order) <- c("(0-0.05]","(0.05-0.1]","(0.1-0.15]","(0.15-0.2]","(0.2-0.25]","(0.25-1]")
```

And the plot creation code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

ggplot.list <- vector(mode="list", length(df.list))
for(g in 1:length(df.list))
{
  if(g==1){ #draw y-axis but no legend
    ggplot.list[[g]] <- ggplot(df.list[[g]], aes(y=log10.p.value,x=category,fill=col))+
      scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE,values=color.order,name="Enrichment P-value",guide=F)+
      geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.2)+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,30),labels=c(seq(0,20,10)," >30"),expand=c(0,0))+
      theme_bw()+theme(panel.border=element_blank(),axis.text=element_text(size=8),axis.title=element_text(size=8,face="bold"))+coord_flip()+theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.1,1,0.1,0.1),"cm"),axis.title.y = element_text(size=8),axis.title.x = element_text(size=8))+labs(x="Category",y="-10log10(P-value)")+ggtitle(names(df.list)[g])
  } else if(g==2){ #no y-axis and no legend
    ggplot.list[[g]] <- ggplot(df.list[[g]], aes(y=log10.p.value,x=category,fill=col))+
      scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE,values=color.order,name="Enrichment P-value",guide=F)+
      geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.2)+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,30),labels = c(seq(0,20,10)," >30"),expand=c(0,0))+
      theme_bw()+theme(panel.border=element_blank(),axis.text=element_text(size=8),axis.title=element_text(size=8,face="bold"))+coord_flip()+theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.1,1,0.1,0.1),"cm"),axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_text(size=8))+labs(y="-10log10(P-value)")+ggtitle(names(df.list)[g])
  } else if(g==3){ #only legend
    ggplot.list[[g]] <- ggplot(df.list[[g]], aes(y=log10.p.value,x=category,fill=col))+
      scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE,values=color.order,name="Enrichment P-value")+
      geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.2)+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,30),labels = c(seq(0,20,10)," >30"),expand=c(0,0))+
      theme_bw()+theme(panel.border=element_blank(),axis.text=element_text(size=8),axis.title=element_text(size=8,face="bold"))+coord_flip()+theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.1,1,0.1,0.1),"cm"),axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_text(size=8))+labs(y="-10log10(P-value)")+ggtitle(names(df.list)[g])
  }
}
```

This gives me almost what I need:
[image]

My problem is that the three figures have different widths. So my question is how do I make the widths identical?

Answer (score 1):

This data seems tailor-made for faceting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

color.order <- c("#7d4343","#B20000","#C74747","#E09898","#EBCCD6","#C8C8C8")
names(color.order) <- c("(0-0.05]","(0.05-0.1]","(0.1-0.15]","(0.15-0.2]","(0.2-0.25]","(0.25-1]")

df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id="grp")
df <- mutate(df, col=factor(col, levels=names(color.order)))

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value, x=category, fill=col))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.2)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,30), labels=c(seq(0,20,10)," >30"), expand=c(0,0))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE, values=color.order, name="Enrichment P-value")
gg <- gg + coord_flip()
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~grp)
gg <- gg + labs(x="Category", y="-10log10(P-value)")
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank(),
                 panel.margin=margin(1,1,1,1, unit="cm"),
                 axis.text=element_text(size=8),
                 axis.title=element_text(size=8,face="bold"),
                 axis.title.y=element_text(size=8),
                 axis.title.x=element_text(size=8),
                 strip.background=element_blank(),
                 plot.margin=margin(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, unit="cm"))
gg
```

[image]